# Rock Paper Scissors Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
var rockPaperScissors = function(rounds) {
  var outcomes = [];
  var plays = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
  var playedSoFar = [];

  var combos = function(roundsToGo) {
    // base case
    if (roundsToGo === 0) {
      outcomes.push(playedSoFar.slice());
      return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < plays.length; i++) {
      playedSoFar.push(plays[i]);
      combos(roundsToGo - 1);
      playedSoFar.pop();
    }
  };
  combos(rounds);
  return outcomes;
};

console.log(rockPaperScissors(2));
```

If I take out the `slice()` from the `playedSoFar`, `outcomes` just gets returned as nine empty arrays, instead of all the combinations from a 2 round rock paper scissors game:

```
[ [ 'rock', 'rock' ],
  [ 'rock', 'paper' ],
  [ 'rock', 'scissors' ],
  [ 'paper', 'rock' ],
  [ 'paper', 'paper' ],
  [ 'paper', 'scissors' ],
  [ 'scissors', 'rock' ],
  [ 'scissors', 'paper' ],
  [ 'scissors', 'scissors' ] ]
```

Why doesn't this work when I take out the `slice()` from the `playedSoFar`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: if I change this line of code to 
outcomes.push(playedSoFar);
it doesn't work for some reason, what is the slice doing

Comment: Have you googled 'what array.slice does'?

Comment: You can't pass an array argument to outcomes

Comment: yeah it returns a copy of the array, but i'm not sure why on the first run through, outcomes doesn't have ['rock', 'rock] in it

Comment: Why don't you go through the recursion step by step (not a long way to go) and see where the problem lies...

Comment: Yeah I know it works when the slice is there, why doesn't it work when there is no slice? did you even read the bottom part of my question

Comment: you can use this also, it will be clearer to you:   outcomes=outcomes.concat(playedSoFar);

Comment: @AaditMShah this isn't a duplicate. The question is unclear, but I believe OP is asking how to generate all the possible combinations from two rounds of rock, paper, & scissors.

Answer (score 1):

`.slice()` returns a copy of your array, if you don't use `.slice()` and just push the `playedSoFar` array then its updated contents will be reflected throughout the scope, therefore they will be reflected in the `combos` array. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Comment: thanks this was a lot more helpful

Comment: No problem. At first, I didn't quite understand what the question was. There are more questions like 'JavaScript pass by reference vs. pass by value' throughout SO if you really want to understand how JavaScript works under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain playedSoFar, then this is the way to go:

```
  outcomes=outcomes.concat(playedSoFar);
```